# remove borders around html input

Tags: css, cross-browser, zurb-foundation

I want to create a search function for my web app.

here are the looks on FF & IE, it is ok without strange border

Firefox

[image]

IE

[image]

and here are the look on Chrome & Safari, it has strange border around the input element

Chrome

[image]

Safari

[image]

Here is my html & css code

```
<input type="search" id="generic_search" onkeypress="return runScript(event)" />
<input type="button" id="generic_search_button" />
```

the `border:0` has been applied to all elements

[image]

```
#generic_search
{
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
#generic_search_button
{
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: White;
    background-image: url(/Images/search.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

How to remove that border?

Comment: Did you try to apply `border: none` directly to `#generic_search`? You also can try `border-color: transparent` just in case, but if the border is displayed, it will still take space.

Comment: `border: 0` should be enough, but if it isn't, perhaps the button's browser-default styling in interfering. Have you tried setting `appearance` to `none` (e.g. `-webkit-appearance: none`)

Comment: @MurraySmith `-webkit-appearance: none` works fine!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`border: 0` should be enough, but if it isn't, perhaps the button's browser-default styling in interfering. Have you tried setting `appearance` to `none` (e.g. `-webkit-appearance: none`)

Answer (score 48):

It's simple

```
input {border:0;outline:0;}
input:focus {outline:none!important;}
```

Answer (score 25):

```
border-width:0px;
border:none;
```

I have used this, and in most of the browsers (Chrome, Safari, FF, IE, etc), it worked fine for me

Answer (score 14):

In my case I am using a CSS framework which adds `box-shadow`, so I had to also add

```
box-shadow: none;
```

So the complete snippet is:

```
border: none; 
border-width: 0; 
box-shadow: none;
```

Comment: Right.  I omitted the standard things for brevity, but you're correct.  I will update the answer for clarity.  Thanks.

Comment: Foundation 6 is an example of a framework which requires this.

Answer (score 6):

I use this css code to remove focus input border some times. Hope will help you -:

```
  input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing, the outline!

Answer (score 2):

your code is look like this  [jsfiddle.net/NTkGZ/](http://jsfiddle.net/NTkGZ/)

try

```
border:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#generic_search_button
{
    float: left;
    width: 24px; /*new width*/
    height: 24px; /*new width*/
    border: none !important; /* no border and override any inline styles*/
    margin-top: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: White;
    background-image: url(/Images/search.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

I think the image size might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
.yourClassName{
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set {border:transparent;}. It doesn´t remove the border but it still doesn´t show.

And as someone said here, set outline:none on focus

Answer (score -1):

use this i hope this help ful to you...
border:none !important;
background-color:transparent;

try this

```
<div id="generic_search"><input type="search" onkeypress="return runScript(event)" /></div>
<button type="button" id="generic_search_button" /></button>
```