# Remove border of input

Tags: html, css, input, border

I have a table where in one `td` there is form  with input and submit button. I want totally remove the box of input. Is it possible?
http://jsfiddle.net/ajeozmwa/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618028/remove-borders-around-html-input

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to remove border and background of your input simply use this code:

```css
input {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
<tr><td id="forReport"><form method="POST"><input name="excelAddress" type="text" value="Калинина 15 а" disabled='disabled'><button type="submit" target="_blank" class="generateReport btn btn-primary btn-sm"></i> button</button></form></td><td>751</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: You may also want to style the input:focus to remove the outline (by setting it to 0)

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your css file:

```
  input:focus,
  input:active {
   box-shadow: none !important;
   -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
   outline: none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `border:none` to the input like this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ajeozmwa/4/).

And if you want to remove background you can use `background:none;` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajeozmwa/5/).

Comment: I think I know you :) your answer is outdated and doesn't work on Chrome; please update so I will be first to upvote "the florin" answer :)